# Vanilla fudge won't set

Tags: fudge

My clotted cream vanilla fudge just won't set. I am using a sugar thermometer. I'm melting my ingredients then bringing the mix to a temp of 115C and cooking at that temp for 20mins before increasing the heat. I've tried taking it to 121C and even last night to a temp of 130C! Then I'm beating with a hand held electric whisk until thick and matte. The fudge tastes delicious but it's still soft and squidgy.

Ingredients are:
275g caster sugar
100g golden syrup
227g tub clotted cream
1/4 teaspoon vanilla paste with seeds

What (else) can I do to make it set?

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but you did pour it in a pan and refrigerate to set, right? The only other thing I can think of right now is to test your thermometer with some boiling water to make sure it's accurate. I had an interesting experience as I waited for my sugar to get to 280F only to notice it caramelising. I'm guessing that can happen in the other direction too. :/

Comment: Is the mixture bubbling at 130C? I just do a rolling boil for 6 minutes (My ingredients are somewhat different though, and I don't use syrup). And mixing with a wooden spoon or spatula only. You may be over mixing it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've tested my themomitor and its spot on. That's what I can't figure out. I melt everything then simmer it at about 115C for 20mins then bring it up to 130C. It darkens and thickens. I'm letting it cool then beating it. I do not put it in the fridge. can anyone give me step by step with temprutures?

Comment: Hmm... I haven't researched enough to really answer, but my guess in that case would be that you haven't beaten it enough. Fudge depends on the right amount of sugar crystallization. Too much and it's grainy and too-hard. Too little and it's going to be too smooth and soft. However, I did see at least one site that actually beat the fudge once it was cooled completely, so maybe you can salvage it? Good luck! https://spatulagoddess.com/how-to-guides/fudge-201-beating-fudge/

Comment: Beating once cool but not completely cold is something I've done in the past it creates a much smoother texture.

Comment: Bad thermometers are not as uncommon as they once were. Accuracy depends on the purity and identity of the fluid used to fill them. I've been lucky enough to find a couple old mercury filled candy/frying thermometers which are trustworthy, but have seen modern "quality brand" red fluid filled thermometers off by as much as 30°F at extreme temps. If you test with boiling water, be sure to factor in your altitude/barometric pressure.

Answer (score 1):

If you live at any altitude other than sea level, you may need to adjust your recipe's temperature. If you live in the mountains as I do, that temperature may vary enough to mess up your recipe, even if you've checked the boiling point of water just prior to starting the candy. The air pressure up here seems more volatile than it was when I lived at sea level. Maybe that's just because one usually doesn't get up to much candy making if there's a hurricane coming in.

At any rate, here's a link to the Unviersity of Utah's [The Art of Candy Making](https://extension.usu.edu/utah/files-ou/TheartofCandyMaking.pdf). It has a chart on page three that will help you adjust your finished temperature (if that should happen to be your problem). I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to it, melt and incorporate some white chocolate to the mixture to help it set up during cooling. The flavor shouldn't alter too far.

Answer (score 0):

for fudge it has to come to a rolling boil before you turn it down to simmer